# Position scrollbar to top after table is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, position, scrollbar

Here is a request some may find a bit simple (I must recognize I do not have much experience with JavaScript).

When the table `id=abcd_tags` value is big, a vertical scrollbar appears.
This is the html code:

```
<tr>
    <td height=100%>
        <div id="section" style="display:none">
            <div id="r">
                <div id="h">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        ...
                        </tr>
                        <tbody id="abcd_tags"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This table is inside a Popup.
Do you know if there is a way to impose the scrollbar cursor to top of the table list and not at bottom when the page loads?(not the browser scroll bar.. the one inside the popup)

Comment: Are you (mis)using `#abcd_tags` as a container for text nodes or are there actually `tr`s in there?

Comment: there are actually tr s. yeah..the table with id abcd_tags is loaded frm databse using java script.
the table is gettng loaded with perfect data.. just the scroll bar in the table is at bottom of list.. which i want to be at top of list